# In Final Fantasy 6 how come Espers are Our Friends if We're Killing Them?

Tags: final-fantasy

http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Magicite

I played Final Fantasy 6. Something I have a hard time understanding is, every time we meet an Esper, we fought them. Then the esper turned into a magicite (which means they're dead), and then we use it.

So that means we're worse than even Kefka.

The esper was still alive when we meet them. Yet after we're done with them they're a corpse.

Maybe I should have asked this in video game stack exchange. However, it's more of the story line instead of the strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget, in the lab in Balance they didn't know about Magicite (and were draining power from living Espers) until your party shows up and blows it all up. Then several of the Espers in the room die en masse, and the researcher was all super-excited as he realized that Magicite would provide more energy then the drain they were attempting from still-living Espers. Those Espers knew that if they died, the bad guys would get all of their power (and kill all Espers on sight), but if they hung on, it would limit the drain potential and force them to expend more resources to capture their brethren alive instead of just killing for Magicite. Compare that to when the Espers agree to help you after their testing you, where they decide you are worthy and give it to you. Yes, they die to give you that power. But Kefka was torturing them for years to get what (comparatively) little power he could, and if he had known to just kill them and use the Magicite... It would have been a full-blown genocide.

Of course then you destroy the Goddess statues, cause magic to cease to exist in the world, and thereby commit said genocide yourself... Albeit it could be argued that they were willing to accept that instead of allow Kefka to continue his tyrannical reign as the lesser of two evils (themselves going out versus everyone suffering for all time).

Answer (score 5):

I played FF6 a long time ago, so don't blindly trust my answer.

At the first time you see a Esper (not in the tutorial, but in the rogue-filled city), the esper willingly commits suicide to make you able to use their power.

Esper's power can be used by human only in magicite form. Magicite are the "soul" of the esper. They still can willingly give you their power (as they do for Terra & co), or be used by force to extract magical energy (as in Kefka's workshop).

I don't remember exactly why you have to fight them, but I believe their was a "honorable death" or "strength test" before willingly giving their magicite. (As opposite as Kefka which create magicite against their will, which is why he can't use their full power).

Comment: He forced them in magicite, he can use their power, but far from their full strenght. Also, I don t emember Kefka using Esper in the final battle, he does have powerful magic, but no esper. (At least on PS1 version)

Comment: Kefka has the statues, he's a God, he doesn't need the espers.

Comment: @AndrewBartel: That s right, but at the second half of the game, maybe in the first half he does use a esper somewhere. He indeed capture esper.

Comment: Yea I think it's implied that he's been using some of the harvested espers from the magitek factory for himself.

Comment: I remember the same thing. They fight you as a measure of whether you're worthy of their power, but they will themselves into magicite. In most cases, at least, you don't actually kill the espers (Doomgaze?).